# how to read json object in python

Tags: python, json, filereader

I have json file named "panamaleaks50k.json". I want to get ['text'] field from the json file but it shows me following error

> the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'

this is my code

```
with open('C:/Users/bilal butt/Desktop/PanamalEakJson.json','r') as lst:
    b = json.loads(lst)
    print(b['text'])
```

my json file look

```
[
{
   "fullname": "Mohammad Fayyaz",
   "id": "885800668862263296",
   "likes": "0",
   "replies": "0",
   "retweets": "0",
   "text": "Love of NS has been shown in PanamaLeaks scandal verified by JIT...",
   "timestamp": "2017-07-14T09:58:31",
   "url": "/mohammadfayyaz/status/885800668862263296",
   "user": "mohammadfayyaz"
 },
{
  "fullname": "TeamPakistanPTI \u00ae",
  "id": "885800910357749761",
  "likes": "0",
  "replies": "0",
  "retweets": "0",
  "text": "RT ArsalanISF: #PanamaLeaks is just a start. U won't believe whr...",
  "timestamp": "2017-07-14T09:59:29",
  "url": "/PtiTeampakistan/status/885800910357749761",
  "user": "PtiTeampakistan"
 }
]
```

how I can read all ['text'] and just single ['text'] field?

Comment: json.load(open('C:/Users/bilal butt/Desktop/PanamalEakJson.json'))['text']

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You should pass the file *contents* (i.e. a string) to [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), not the file object itself. Try this:

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    print(data[0]['text'])
```

There's also the [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) function which accepts a *file* object and does the `f.read()` part for you under the hood.

Comment: it's amusing how a single letter 's' makes the difference. IMHO these 2 function methods naming should've been more notable between one another.

Comment: @programmer dreamer the `s` indicates that this parse a string.

Comment: Perfect, this helped me.

Answer (score 23):

Use `json.load()`, not `json.loads()`, if your input is a file-like object (such as a TextIOWrapper).

Given the following complete reproducer:

```
import json, tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    f.write(b'{"text": "success"}'); f.flush()
    with open(f.name,'r') as lst:
        b = json.load(lst)
        print(b['text'])
```

...the output is `success`.

Comment: Flagged community-wiki to avoid harvesting rep from a known dupe. Folks should feel free to edit/amend, though the linked answer should be considered more canonical.

Comment: i got this error by using **load()** funciton.   ` the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'`

Comment: @BilalButt, `load()` does not generate that error -- unlike `loads()`, which the code in the question uses, `load()` accepts file-like objects as input. If you assert that it does, edit your question to add a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code someone else can run, without modifications, to see the problem themselves. (Right now the indentation is wrong, and nobody but you will have a `C:\Users\bilal butt` directory, so this isn't code other people can invoke).

Comment: thanks for your quick rply .. i edit json file in my Question.

Comment: The contents of the file aren't relevant -- the file could just contain `[]` and the error would be exactly the same. Thus, a *minimal* reproducer has no need to include anything more than `[]` as the file contents being parsed (but *should* actually create a file with those contents, if it can't be reproduced without one).

Comment: @BilalButt, ...see the edit I made to your question, such that the code can be copied-and-pasted to produce the problem *even if the file doesn't exist beforehand*, and the edit made to this answer, to let the answer be tested in the same way (with a copy-and-paste-style test).