# Can I filter all the data1 values from a json file using python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, filter

I'm trying to filter all the data1 values from a json file and output them to a file.
The json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "data1": "1234", 
    "data2": "8972a" 
  },
  {
    "data1": "7531", 
    "data2": "5568b" 
  }
]
```

I'm still trying to open the file but I constantly get an error saying:

```
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper
```

this is my code:

```py
import json

filename = "C:\\Path\\To\\File\\file.json"
input_json = json.loads(open(filename, 'r'))
```

I'm trying to get a file with:

```
1234
7531
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON file is invalid. Try this:

```
[
  {
    "data1": "1234",
    "data2": "8972a"
  },
  {
    "data1": "7531",
    "data2": "5568b"
  }
]
```

Use this link to find out a possible solution:
*[how to read json object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857154/how-to-read-json-object-in-python)*